# Combining an outcome of a score

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, calculus-of-variations, integer-partitions

Hey I was wondering how many are the possibilities of combining the scored points of a result such $133:75$ from a basketball game? Considering that there are fouls($1$ point), normal($2$ points) and threes($3$ points)?

Comment: It is ONLY for 1 and 2 points: I have come up with $\sum^{n-1=132}_{k=67} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \cdot \sum^{n-1=74}_{k=38} \binom{n-1}{k-1}$, where k is the number of summands, which sum up to 133 and 75. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using generating functions. This is analogous to the classic [coin change problem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/GeneratingFunctions.shtml).

In your case, you want to look at the term for $x^{133}$ in the expansion of
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x^1)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}.$$
We may rewrite $f$ as
$$ f(x) = \frac{1/6}{(1-x)^3} + \frac{1/4}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{17/72}{1-x}
+ \frac{1/8}{1+x} + \frac{-j/9}{x-j} + \frac{-j^2/9}{x-j^2},$$ 
with $j^2 + j + 1 = 0$. By expanding each fraction $(a-x)^{-d} = a^{-d} (1-x/a)^{-d} = a^{-d} \sum \binom{d}{n} (x/a)^n$, we may obtain an exact formula for the coefficient $a_n$ of $x^n$ in $f$; namely
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{6} (-1)^n\binom{-3}{n} + \frac{1}{4} (-1)^n\binom{-2}{n} + \frac{17}{72} + \frac{1}{8} (-1)^n + \frac{1}{9} (j^n + j^{2n}).
$$
Using this, I find $a_{133} = 1541$ and $a_{75} = 507$.

Comment: So, what is the total number for the whole game?